# Infinite Family of Open Intervals disjoint, then The family must be numerable

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

i'm new on this. If we have a infinite family $\{A_{\lambda}\}_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ of open intervals such $$A_{\lambda_1}\cap A_{\lambda_2}=\emptyset\;\;,\forall\lambda_1,\lambda_2\in\Lambda$$ then $\Lambda$ is numerable (biyection to $\mathbb{N}$)

Why?, I can't prove this and i'm feel bad for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: each interval contains a rational number.

Answer (score 0):

For $m,n\in\mathbb N$ let
$$\Lambda_{m,n}=\{\lambda\in\Lambda:A_\lambda\text{ is contained in }[-m,m]\text{ and has length }\ge\frac1n\}.$$
Since $\Lambda=\bigcup_{m,n\in\mathbb N}\Lambda_{m,n}$ and $|\Lambda_{m,n}|\le2mn$, $\Lambda$ is the union of countably many finite sets, and therefore is countable.